# How to add multiple records in same table at one button click in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am entering data with the same date but at different times of the day.

I need to input in the table each record with different times.

Comment: I think you forgot to include your code, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for the response. @Tommi

Comment: Great job! If you are asking questions in the future try to have in mind to include a codesnippet that shows what part of the code that's not working. You can check more about it here [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)